# How to remove s4-ribbonrow from modal-dialog without having any access to masterpage or SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: modal-dialog

I'm challenging myself for a few hours now attempting to remove the `s4-ribbonrow` from a modal dialog window (as marked in my screenshot). I found several solutions on the web, which all require SharePoint Designer 2013 or any access to the SP master page. The problem is, that I am only responsible for some page which is far under the top level site and therefore I only could switch it off with Script Editor WebPart.
I've tried to code it like:

```
<script>
.s4-ribbonrow {
    display: none;
}
</script>
```

But unfortunately it doesn’t change anything and I still can see the ribbon.

[image: s4-ribbonrow]

Comment: Try to change the first line to <script type="text/css">. And did you add the script editor to the actual list page or the actual form? The script editor should must be added to the actual form pages, newform.aspx, dispform.aspx and editform.aspx.

Comment: s4-ribbonrow is an ID but you're using it as a class. See the answer below.

Comment: Check first if your Modal dialog is displayed in an Iframe, if so any CSS you add in its parent will not be applied. You then have to get to the original-nonh-Iframed page and inject the CSS there with a CEWP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Script Editor than please use below mentioned code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var suitebar = $("#suiteBar");
if(suitebar.length<1)
$("#s4-ribbonrow").css('display','none');
</script>
```

Add following CSS in your form pages like newform.aspx, dispform.aspx and editform.aspx, this way the ribbon will only be hidden in dialog view, and still usable in normal view.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-dialog #s4-ribbonrow, .ms-dialog .ms-cui-topBar2, .ms-dialog .s4-notdlg, .ms-dialog .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .ms-dialog .s4-notdlg noindex, .ms-dialog #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, .ms-dialog #s4-titlerow, .ms-dialog #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, .ms-dialog #s4-leftpanel-content {display:none !important;}
    .ms-dialog .s4-ca{margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;}
    </style>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for solving my issue

Comment: If so than please mark & upvote it as correct so other can get benefit of it.... Thanks

Comment: Done. I will have to gain some more points on this site that my upvotes will count. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Try that CSS by marking as `!important` and also ensure that it must load after all your CSS files are loaded

Answer (score 2):

Try the following CSS:

```
.ms-dialog div#s4-ribbonrow {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
.ms-cui-tabContainer 
{

    display: none;
}


.ms-cui-tt {

    display:none;    
}
```